# Creating a mysql event based database

Tags: mysql

So initially I was thinking something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_name` VARCHAR(200),
    `date_added` DATETIME
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `event_date` (
    `event_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATE,
    `end_date` DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY event_id REFERENCES events(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE `event_times` (
    `event_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `event_date` DATE,
    `start_time` TIME,
    `end_time` TIME,
    FOREIGN KEY event_id REFERENCES events(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Would it be possible to make sure that the even_times.event_date falls within the event_date.start_date and event_date.end_date range, with this schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this structure I think you cover the needs that explain

```
CREATE TABLE events(
  event_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  date_added DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
);

CREATE TABLE event_date(
  event_date_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_date_id),
  INDEX FK_event_date_events_event_id (event_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_event_date_events_event_id FOREIGN KEY (event_id)
  REFERENCES events (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE event_times(
  event_time_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_date_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  start_time TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  end_time TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_time_id),
  INDEX FK_event_times_event_date_event_date_id (event_date_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_event_times_event_date_event_date_id FOREIGN KEY (event_date_id)
  REFERENCES event_date (event_date_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

;

Comment: I came to the same conclusion on table structure after some coffee. I'm give you the nod on this. Thanks for taking the stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to create event details, where an event can occur in one or more dates, each date can have one or more hours of completion.

If so, it would be desirable to establish relationships in a "cascade", where even referenced in EVENT_DATE, and in turn is related even_date with even_time, eliminating the date field in the table even_time

Comment: Basically, I am working with events like a concert that can take place over n days, with different start and end times for the whole concert. Then I'll have time slots for each group. So really I'm just trying to get after the best setup within the database that would allow for the most accuracy and least amount of code later.